# Should I worry – [cloudthumbnails.client] Could not copy memory to make the thumbnail count against my jetsam limit

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my SwiftUI app I show a list of thumbnails for all images in a directory. I use the following code fragment to generate the thumbnail:

```
let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(fileAt: file.url,
                                                       size: CGSize(width: Common.thumbnailSize, height: Common.thumbnailSize),
                                                       scale: 1.0, representationTypes: .thumbnail)
            
            QLThumbnailGenerator.shared.generateBestRepresentation(for: request) { [weak self] (thumbnail, _) in
...
```

All works well. The thumbnails are shown in a SwiftUI HStack, and generate in a nice lazy manner. However I can get the following output on the console:

```
[cloudthumbnails.client] Could not copy memory to make the thumbnail count against my jetsam limit
```

Do I need to worry, and if so what could I do to stop this from happening?